# AJAX allowed inside app project files

Tags: html, ajax, cordova

Is AJAX allowed between files that are inside the same app project?
Is this allowed in the 5 main browsers?
Should I use any specific header, or any $.ajax(~) special property to specify my intentions?
I will use Phonegap, by the way.
Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Your app runs a local website on your device. Relative file urls work fine

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'page.html', true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
    xhr.status === 200 ? success() : failure();
  }
};
xhr.send();
```